# max_matches using SphinxQL

Tags: sphinx

Apparently max_matches is deprecated in the current Sphinx so it has to be commented out in the confi file.  I am using SphinxQL in a MySql editor.

When I use limit 10,000 I still only get 1000

When I use option max_matches = 20000 I get 20

When I use them both together, limit 20000 option max_matches = 20000 I get 20,000. Should I have to use both together and would that affect performance is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its **only** the 'server' variable `max_matches` that is depreciated. It is **still a run-time variable**.

Set it as big as you need it. No bigger.

Comment: Yes but the interesting thing was to make it work in SphinxQL I had to also include the mysql limit option as per above. So if I am trying to get ALL matches in a db I need push a variable that matches my db size or is there some 'option ALL' I can use?

Comment: Yes, LIMIT defaults to 20 if not specified, so need to specify it. There is no blind 'get all regardless' option.